# How to group hough transform lines using rho and theta

Tags: python, image-processing, grouping, line, hough-transform

I'm having trouble trying to group lines obtained using the hough transform, where I have the following information: rho (distance) and theta (angle) for each line.

The problem is that for the same location, it is generating more than one line, and I cannot change the parameters of the hough. Here comes the challenge, I need to group the nearby lines and extract only one. I tried to group only by angle or just by distance using a limit, but I realized that one depends on the other (there may be several lines with the same angle, but with different distances and vice versa) and I need to use both information , but I cannot do this task.

My python code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def drawLines(thetas, rhos):
    
    img_black = np.zeros((240, 320, 3), np.uint8) #empty image 240x320 just for draw the lines
    
    origin = np.array((0, img_black.shape[1]))
    
    for theta, rho in zip(thetas, rhos):
        degree = abs(theta*(180/np.pi)) #radian to degree
        if(not (degree >= 45 and degree <= 120)): #limiting horizontal lines
            y0, y1 = (rho - origin * np.cos(theta)) / np.sin(theta)
            xx1, yy1 = (0, int(y0))
            xx2, yy2 = (img_black.shape[1], int(y1))
            cv2.line(img_black, (xx1, yy1), (xx2, yy2), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            
    return img_black

#array containing angles at [:, 0] and distances at [:, 1].
lines = np.array([[ 0.240651248,  143.679599499],
                  [-0.538183700,  150.688360451],
                  [-0.179394567,  157.697121402],
                  [ 0.599440381,  110.638297872],
                  [ 0.021877386,  172.715894869],
                  [ 0.415670337,  143.679599499]])

thetas = lines[:, 0]
rhos = lines[:, 1]

img_lines = drawLines(thetas, rhos)

#showing the original result:
plt.imshow(img_lines)
```

Output: 
[image]
When I manually remove lines 0 and 2 with the code below, I get the result I want, but I need to automate this.

```
deleted = [0, 2] #indexs deleted lines
thetas2 = np.delete(thetas, deleted)
rhos2 = np.delete(rhos, deleted)

img_lines2 = drawLines(thetas2, rhos2)

plt.imshow(img_lines2)
```

Output: 
[image]
In addition to the data in the lines above, there are variations of this problem (where I want only one line in each group found), such as:

```
lines2 = np.array([[ 0.354413656,  112.640801001],
                   [-0.520681791,  131.664580726],
                   [-0.450674155,  149.687108886],
                   [ 0.039379295,  164.705882353],
                   [-0.083134067,  148.685857322],
                   [ 0.573187518,  125.657071339],
                   [-0.126888840,  138.673341677],
                   [-0.739455652,  137.672090113],
                   [-0.205647430,  121.652065081],
                   [-0.363164610,  166.708385482],
                   [-0.774459470,  126.658322904],
                   [-0.223149339,  183.729662078]])

thetas3 = lines2[:, 0]
rhos3 = lines2[:, 1]

img_lines3 = drawLines(thetas3, rhos3)

plt.imshow(img_lines3)
```

Output: 
[image]
I hope you can help me, I am already trying to create a solution for this, but so far I have not obtained any results.

Comment: *"I cannot change the parameters of the hough"* why?

Comment: @Bilal Why I was asked to use the hough from the skimage library and there are only two parameters there: image and theta, and I ended up in this situation, I know I may be on the wrong track, but this problem is driving me crazy because it doesn't seem impossible, but it doesn't I can group these lines.